# Make a one simple code from several similar code

Tags: matlab

Hello everybody I have a very simple problem, I have too many data y, p and r. So I want to calculate it in a single code.

This an example of my code if I breakdown into separate code

```
y1=45
y2=56
y3=67
p1=34
p2=45
p3=56
r1=23
r2=34
r3=45
Ryaw1=[cosd(y1) -sind(y1) 0;
      sind(y1) cosd(y1) 0;
      0 0 1]
Rpitch1=[cosd(p1) 0 sind(p1);
        0 1 0;
        -sind(p1) 0 cos(p1)]
Rroll1=[1 0 0;
       0 cosd(r1) -sind(r1);
       0 sind(r1) cosd(r1)]
R1=Ryaw1*Rpitch1*Rroll1
Coordinate1=R1*X0
Ryaw2=[cosd(y2) -sind(y2) 0;
      sind(y2) cosd(y2) 0;
      0 0 1]
Rpitch2=[cosd(p2) 0 sind(p2);
        0 1 0;
        -sind(p2) 0 cos(p2)]
Rroll2=[1 0 0;
       0 cosd(r2) -sind(r2);
       0 sind(r2) cosd(r2)]
R2=Ryaw2*Rpitch2*Rroll2
Coordinate2=R2*X0
Ryaw3=[cosd(y3) -sind(y3) 0;
      sind(y3) cosd(y3) 0;
      0 0 1]
Rpitch3=[cosd(p3) 0 sind(p3);
        0 1 0;
        -sind(p3) 0 cos(p3)]
Rroll3=[1 0 0;
       0 cosd(r3) -sind(r3);
       0 sind(r3) cosd(r3)]
R3=Ryaw3*Rpitch3*Rroll3
Coordinate3=R3*X0
Coordinate=[Cooedinate1 Coordinate2 Coordinate3]
```

The goals is to find "Coordinate" (in matrix - combined from Coordinate1, Coordinate2, Coordinate3, .... ,Coordinate..) from every y, p and r data with the same "X0" as a single primary data for calculation.

Sorry for my bad english,

Thanks :)

Comment: Make `y,p,r` as arrays instead of individual variables. Then you can use a for loop to compute the `Coordinate` matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vectors and matrices instead of individual scalars. These are indexed in almost the same way as you had before, i.e. `y1` becomes `y(1)`.

Then you can easily loop over the code 3 times and save the repetition.

See my commented code below.

```
% Define some X0. This should be a column vector.
X0 = [1; 2; 3];
% Make y,p,r into 3 element vectors
y = [45 56 67];
p = [34 45 56];
r = [23 34 45];
% Make R, Ryaw, Rpitch and Rroll 3x3x3 matrices
R = zeros(3,3,3);
Ryaw = zeros(3,3,3);
Rpitch = zeros(3,3,3);
Rroll = zeros(3,3,3);
% Make Coordinate a 3x3 matrix
Coordinate = zeros(3,3);
% Loop k from 1 to 3
% For each 3x3x3 matrix, the kth 3x3 matrix is equivalent to your Ryawk, Rpitchk, Rrollk, Rk
for k = 1:3
    Ryaw(:,:,k)  = [cosd(y(k)) -sind(y(k))  0
                    sind(y(k))  cosd(y(k))  0
                    0           0           1];

    Rpitch(:,:,k)= [cosd(p(k))  0           sind(p(k))
                    0           1           0
                    -sind(p(k)) 0           cos(p(k))];

    Rroll(:,:,k) = [1   0          0
                    0   cosd(r(k)) -sind(r(k))
                    0   sind(r(k)) cosd(r(k))];

    R(:,:,k) = Ryaw(:,:,k)*Rpitch(:,:,k)*Rroll(:,:,k);
    Coordinate(:,k) = R(:,:,k)*X0;
end
disp(Coordinate)
```

Comment: Thanks, for the help, it works. But the coordinate result still false. it should be:

`5.447846662126555
-1.188204001796331
-2.669379847688314`

if I enter y=45, p=30 and r=50

Comment: @BrianBarito What is your `X0` for those inputs though?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forget to mention the X0. This is the primary code:

`X0=[5;-3;3]
y=45
p=30
r=50`

and the result is approach:

`X1=[5.920;-0.057;-2.280]`

Thanks :)

Comment: @BrianBarito Both my code and your code return `X1=[5.9197;-0.0575;-2.5570]` for those inputs, why do you expect different?